# Changing Values in Row 0 of Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm having trouble changing the values in a numpy array. I have already set up the array of zeros.  Pvfv is present value and future value

```
pvfv=np.zeros((7,5))
print(pvfv)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00]
 [ 0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00]
 [ 0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00]
 [ 0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00]
 [ 0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00]
 [ 0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00]
 [ 0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00]]
```

Now I want to use np.array change row 0 to look like, keeping the rest of the array constant:

```
 [[ 0.00     1.00     2.00     3.00     4.00]
  [ 0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00]
  [ 0.00     .....
```

Comment: `pvfv=np.zeros((7,5)); pvfv[0,:] = np.array([i for i in range(pvfv.shape[1])])`

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
import numpy as np

n = 7
p = 5
zeros = np.zeros((n, p))
print("before: \n", zeros, "\n")

row = np.arange(0, p, dtype = float) #no need to copy but just to make things clear.
zeros[0] = row;
print("after: \n", zeros, "\n")
```

output:

```
before: 
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]] 

after: 
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand. Is adding the dtype =float necessary in all scenarios?

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case as the matrix entries (i.e. row 0) will be casted to the original type of the matrix e.g. numpy.float64.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the top row and then stack it above the rest:

```
np.vstack((np.arange(5), np.zeros((6, 5))))
```